# Recursive SQL Query, but not the usual kind of recursive

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, recursive-query

I have a set of tables that organize a group of people into teams.

- Users (ID int PK, etc.)
- Teams (ID int PK, etc.)
- UsersToTeams (ID int PK, UserID int FK, TeamID int FK, TeamSupervisor bit not null)

There is no Parent ID in the table because users can be on any number of teams, and teams can have any number of supervisors.  A user may be on six teams but only supervise two of them, and one or both of those supervised teams may have other supervisors in it.  So my hierarchy looks more like a web than a tree.

I recognize that a recursive query may result in a circular reference. Assume the software is handling that for the moment.

The company hierarchy is described by a Supervisor supervising a team of Users, a Manager supervising a team of Supervisors, etc.  So it's hierarchical, but not in the usual way.

I need a query which, given a UserID, will return the IDs of the users he supervises, down infinite levels.  How might such a query go?

*Example*

```
Users (ID, Name)
1 Archie
2 Betty
3 Chuck
4 Dilton
5 Eddie
6 Fannie
```

User 1 is a Manager (level 3).  Users 2 and 3 are Supervisors (level 2). Users 4, 5, 6 are Users (level 1).

```
Teams (ID, Name)
1 Team Alpha
2 Team Bravo
3 Sup Team

UsersToTeams (ID INT PK, UserID INT FK, TeamID INT FK, isSupervisor BIT)
1 1 3 1  -- Archie supervises Sup Team
2 2 3 0  -- Betty is a member of Sup Team
3 3 3 0  -- Chuck is a member of Sup Team
4 2 1 1  -- Betty supervises team Alpha
5 4 1 0  -- Dilton is a member of team Alpha
6 5 1 0  -- Eddie is a member of team Alpha
7 3 2 1  -- Chuck supervises Team Bravo
8 6 2 0  -- Fannie is a member of Team Bravo
```

- Archie is a Manager, supervising a team of supervisors.
- Betty is a Supervisor, supervising a team of users.
- Chuck is a Supervisor, supervising a team of users.
- Betty and Chuck are *also* on Archie's team, but do not supervise it.

Therefore:

1. If I pass in UserID 5 (Eddie), I should get back only 5, because Eddie doesn't supervise anyone.
2. If I pass in UserID 3 (Chuck), I should get back 3 and 6, because Fannie is on a team that Chuck supervises.
3. If I pass in UserID 1 (Archie), I should get back all UserIDs described here, because Betty and Chuck are on Archie's team, and everyone else is on either Betty's team or Chuck's team.

Sorry, I tried that SQL fiddle link, but after 15 minutes of "Building Schema" I lost hope for it.

Comment: Could you setup some sample data? You can use http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6

Comment: and also the expected result set along with the sample data

Comment: Perhaps this will help, it appears to be a thorough explanation of what you want to do : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: Added example data as requested.  SqlFiddle never did finish building the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE.

First, select the user himself, and then recursively select all the user he's immediately supervising over:

```
declare @userID int = 1;

with u as (
  select id from users where id = @userID
  union all
  select lacky.userID from u supervisor
  join usersToTeams supervising on supervising.userID = supervisor.id and isSupervisor = 1
  join usersToTeams lacky on lacky.teamID = supervising.teamID and lacky.isSupervisor = 0
)

select * from u
```

Here's the fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/525e1/3

Comment: Thanks.  Incidentally, this seemed like a bad way to design things; not really fully 1NF. Any ideas on a better layout?

Comment: @tsilb Sorry, I don't know much about the normal forms. I just make it work. =D Your schema looks pretty good to me. The only change I might do is one of the following: 1. remove UsersToTeams.ID and change the primary key to (UserID, TeamID) or 2. apply a uniqueness constraint to make sure a user is not on the same team twice.